# Local Storage variable

Tags: javascript, html

I  hope someone can help me with defining the value for my variable "time". when I console log to see if if the var time is working, it return "Undefined"  My JavaScript and HTML looks like this (thanks in advance!):

lang-js -->

```
    var text = $(this).siblings(".description").val();
    var time = $(this).attr("id");
//This is where he have to save the text to LocalStorage using "setItem"    
localStorage.setItem(time,text);

console.log(time)
```

```html
 <!-- time -->
    <div class="time-block row">
      <div class="hour col-2">9:00am</div>

      <!--Text area-->
      <textarea id="9" class="description col-8 "></textarea>

<!-- Save Button -->

      <button class="saveBtn col-2">Save</button>
    </div>
   
    <div class="time-block row">
      <div class="hour col-2">10:00am</div>
      <textarea id="10" class="description col-8"></textarea>
      <button class="saveBtn col-2">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select by id to get value input, see:
You can test using this link: https://jsfiddle.net/at4exz1v/

```js
$(".saveBtn").click(ev => {
  const input1 = $('#9').val();
  const input2 = $('#10').val();

  localStorage.setItem('input_01', input1);
  localStorage.setItem('input_02', input2);
  
  const storageItems = { ...localStorage };

  console.log(`Input 1: ${input1}, Input 2: ${input2}`);
  console.log(`Your Storage Local:`, storageItems);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="time-block row">
  <div class="hour col-2">9:00am</div>
  <textarea id="9" class="description col-8 ">9:21</textarea>
  <button class="saveBtn col-2">Save</button>
</div>

<div class="time-block row">
  <div class="hour col-2">10:00am</div>
  <textarea id="10" class="description col-8">10:45</textarea>
  <button class="saveBtn col-2">Save</button>
</div>
```